# How to prioritize internet usage on a LAN through a mecer router

Tags: networking, windows-xp, router

We have 4 desktop Pc's and 1 wireless laptop all running off 1 Mecer 4 port router.
2 of the desktop Pc and the laptop are running windows 7 while the other 2 desktop Pc are using windows xp.
The Pc that the router connects to is running windows 7.
My Pc (xp) , the one that most frequently uses the internet for work is also the pc that suffers the most when all 4 are connected to the internet.
My sons use the other 3 Pc's to either play online games or watch youtube and when this happens , all my work goes to hell in a handbasket.

How can I set up the router to make My work pc the priority ?

Comment: Does your router support QoS? Check the manual if you don't know what QoS stands for.

Answer (score 0):

You make it sound like your computer is what the Internet modem/gateway is connected to, and you're sharing the internet connection through your computer instead of the router (which is what a router is meant to do).

Is this how you have it set up?

[image: Is this how you have it set up?]

Because it should be set up like this:

[image: Because it should be set up like this]

After that; the answer is, it depends on how much effort you want to put into it.  I'm not familiar with your router, but most routers should support some form of QoS (Quality of Service).  Basically, you go into your router configuration, to the QoS configuration, and set your computer's MAC address as top priority, if your device supports that functionality.  This *usually* works in theory, but in practice, not always.

Your router might even support service QoS, which lets you determine what services get higher priority, but you'd have to know what ports the services are running on.

Example:

- Port 80 for HTTP
- Port 443 for HTTPS
- Port 29275 for some video games (google the video game + port for correct port)

This won't necessarily resolve all your issues, because video websites are still HTTP/HTTPS.

This is the best you can do with *home* solutions.  Anything more would require expensive equipment.  You're better off buying a second internet connection at that price point.

Comment: Thank you very much for this advise , I can see why it sounds like our home setup is like your first diagram , but it is not , I am perhaps just a bit of a layman in trying to explain our setup. My router does support QOS and when i go on that page , I freeze , I am dead scared to enter anything in any of the places as I do not fully understand what needs to be done. This is exactly how the page looks like http://screenshots.portforward.com/routers/Mecer/E5104N2/IP_QoS.htm

Comment: First, you need to figure out what port your computer (the one you want to have highest priority) is physically connected to on the router.  Put that value in the `Physical Port` value, then change the Outbound Priority to `Highest`, then click Add.  You can do something similar for the other stuff you want to limit, by finding their Physical Port on the router, and deciding what Priority you want them to have.